# how to parse .in files using python and write contents to .out file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, parsing

How do I parse a .in file? I have tried with python but all I get is a bunch of \x00
please help.

```
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
```

Comment: `.in` does not seem like a well-known standard format, please specify where it comes from.

Comment: they are input files for m4 macro preprocessor

Comment: I just need to read the file

Comment: I need to get the clear content printed of the file

Comment: While I do not know `m4`, based on Wikipedia they seem to be text files. The simple `open()` can work with text files, or how do you try? Can it happen that another process is still writing to the same file?

Comment: What code are you using to read the file? Is there a document describing its format, and if so please provide a link to it.